# Run HLM mediation in R

Tags: r, glm, lme4

I try to run HLM mediation with the "mediation" package:

```
med.fit <- glmer(M ~ treat + control  + (1|subject_id) ,family = binomial(link = "logit"), data = R1_data)

out.fit <- glmer(Y ~ M+ treat + control+ (1 + M|subject_id),family = binomial(link = "logit"), data = R1_data)

med.out <- mediate(med.fit, out.fit, treat = "treat", mediator = "M", sims = 1000)
```

I got this error message:

> Error in `[.data.frame`(y.data, int.term.name[p]) : undefined columns selected

How to solve this problem?

Here is the original data and code:

```
names(R1_data)

 [1] "subject_id"                                                                            
 [3] "Presented_is_solvable"                                                                   
 [5] "JOS"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
[17] "Answer_JOS"                                                                                                                 
[23] "Matrix_Z_score" 

library(mediation)
library(lme4)

med.fit <- glmer(JOS ~ Matrix_Z_score + Presented_is_solvable  + (1|subject_id) ,family = binomial(link = "logit"), data = R1_data)

out.fit <- glmer(Answer_JOS ~ JOS + Matrix_Z_score +Presented_is_solvable  + (1 + JOS|subject_id),family = binomial(link = "logit"), data = R1_data)

med.out <- mediate(med.fit, out.fit, treat = "Matrix_Z_score", mediator = "JOS", sims = 1000)
```

Comment: Error messages point out precisely where the user is going wrong. You have selected columns that are not defined in the data frame.

Comment: All the columns are defined, I checked it. The med.fit and out.fit ran O.K and they are built from the same columns.

Comment: Hello Tirza, would be post the code of your dataset please ? Best regards.

Comment: Were you able to fix this? Show us more of the code as well as the first few rows of the data frames.

Comment: I didn't fix it yet.

Comment: I wrote above the original data frame and code

Answer (score 1):

Figured out that this happens when treatment or mediator data is classified as factor data in R. The mediate function can't properly locate the names of those variables from the fitted models as in the models, they are displayed as "variablename"+factor level.

The solution is to make sure those variables are classified as integers. You can take a look at the variable classifications in the `student` data set within the mediation package.